# Killing a query before any data arrives

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've got a fairly large collection and make non-indexed (intentionally) queries that may take a long time to return the first batch of results, or to indicate failure. I want these queries to fail if nothing gets returned in say 10 seconds. So I wrote this:

```
try:
     cur = big_collection.find(query, network_timeout=10)
     for doc in cur:
          print doc
except pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect:
     print "failure!"
```

This works fine on the client, however, `current_op` says that the query continues executing on the server even after the timeout. I tried `cur.close()` and `db.kill_cursors` in the `except` block, but that didn't work, probably because `cur.cursor_id` remains `None` until it receives any data from the server.

Is there a way to kill a query even if it hasn't returned any data yet?

Answer (score 2):

There are no PyMongo wrappers, but you can use the related database commands to query for the opid and kill the operation. It will look something like: [`db['$cmd.sys.killop'].find_one({op:op})`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Viewing+and+Terminating+Current+Operation#comment-89149418). For some reason, [this doesn't seem to work with PyMongo 2.1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/1wFp7AqWnM4/iidDVbK0fiQJ).

See:

- [Viewing and Terminating Current Operation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Viewing+and+Terminating+Current+Operation)
- [PyMongo API: `command()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command) (PyMongo command wrapper? Note it was not used above...)

Comment: Thanks! I thought about that. Any idea how to obtain `opid` from a Cursor object?